# Intel hd3000 with HDMI output causes USB mouse and keyboard conflicts?

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, intel-graphics, hdmi

I really don't know where to look for help with this problem, so I'm starting here.

I am running a clean install of 12.10, on Gigabyte z68a-dh3-b3 mobo, Core i5 2500K, integrated Intel HD 3000 (Sandy Bridge). Dual Monitor setup; Samsung (1440x900) on DVI and Acer (HD 1080p) on HDMI.

Whenever the HDMI output is "active", i.e. Acer screen configured "On" in Display Settings, my wireless keyboard and mouse are *very* unresponsive - characters dropped while typing, and mouse super slow. When I configure the Acer screen "Off", everything immediately returns to normal.

The questions I have are is this an Intel Graphics driver issue ? A USB issue ? An Xorg issue ? Just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

There's some weirdness with Sandybridge graphics right now. I have a Mini-ITX AsRock Z68 board + a 2500k, and I use the iGPU with all three displays connected (VGA monitor + DVI  monitor + HDMI projector), with any one of them disabled at any given time since it can't drive all three at once. I too have some occasional stability issues that are hard to reproduce and aren't documented anywhere (though my wireless KB + mouse are fine).

12.04 was fine, but since going to 12.10 things have been tricky, and I eventually switched to 13.04 sources about a month ago because I wasn't having any luck. I've had the best luck with kernel 3.8.06; hopefully this will get straightened out in the relase version of Raring.

Comment: Interesting, our configs are very similar. Do you run 64 or 32 bit ? I am on 64 bit. I'm leery of moving forward to 13.04 right now. Would the brand of wireless keybd/mouse matter ? Mine is Microsoft 800 wireless keybd/mouse. Maybe I should just move to 13.04 and see.

Comment: I have a Logitech K360 and M310. They work well, but like I said, I have other issues completely unrelated to the mouse and keyboard. With Kernel 3.8.06, X occasionally locks up when I'm using 2D video acceleration (VLC or Skype), but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

So I followed serilain's lead and moved on to 13.04, and confirm problem went away immediately. I cannot report if the solution was in the graphics driver, usb, or anything else.

Comment: Good to hear! Unfortunately, 13.04 isn't supported here yet, but I think the lesson for now is not to take "stable" versions of xorg-intel or the kernel at face value unless they're in an LTS version ... it's like we already have rolling releases, we just aren't calling them that yet!

Comment: oh, and I forgot to mention above -- I'm on x64 too.